# SAS PROC SQL: How to add trailing spaces?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a problem like this at work:

Some system requires a specific input like:

```
0000051420189999999                         ABC12345678<20 SPACES>;
```

Which is a `(some digit)` + `Sample_Date` + `(some digit)` + `x amount of spaces` + `Sample_KEY` + `y amount of spaces`.

I read a few online post about string concatenation and converting date into string. But the trailing spaces are always eliminated at the end.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.MAINFRAME_FILE AS 
SELECT CAT('0000', 
           COMPRESS(PUT((Sample_Date), MMDDYY10.), '/',),
           '9999999                         ', 
           Sample_KEY,
           '                                          ') 
           AS INPUT FORMAT=$100.
FROM WORK.TEST
;
QUIT;
```

How can I add some trailing spaces at the end, say 20? Thanks

Comment: Do you need that value in a variable or written to a text file?  If the latter then use pointer controls on the PUT statement.

Comment: What does PROC SQL have to do with the question?

Comment: I've usually only seen this with text files as fixed width files. Is that what you're trying to do here?

Comment: @Reeza Yes, you are correct. I am using virtual version of SAS EG, it has no access to write file. But I can manually export a dataset, or setup export as a "step". Ultimately I need it in a text file format...

Answer (score 2):

If you're putting this into a SAS dataset, the spaces are there automatically as long as the field length is defined sufficiently.  All SAS columns are by definition space-padded to full length. You might not see them depending on how you're looking at the field, but they're there internally.

If you're putting this into a SQL Server table or similar, it will probably depend on the particular RDBMS you're connecting to how to accomplish this.

SAS example - note `x` has the ascii representation '20'x which is space:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.MAINFRAME_FILE AS 
SELECT CAT('0000', 
           COMPRESS(PUT((today()), MMDDYY10.), '/',),
           '9999999                         ', 
           Name,
           '                                          ') 
           AS INPUT FORMAT=$100.
FROM SASHELP.CLASS
;
QUIT;

data your_file;
  set work.mainframe_file;
  x = substr(input,60,1);
  put x= $HEX2.;
run;
```

Comment: What does the substr(input, 60,1) do? Is it for demonstrating there is an actual space there?

Comment: It is.  (There is always an actual space there in a SAS dataset, whether I put it there or not - leave off the last `'                   '` and you can still see it there.)

Comment: It might be clearer to use the `repeat` function rather than typing out n spaces like that.

Comment: @Joe I am using virtual version of SAS EG, it has no access to write file. But I can manually export a dataset, or setup as a step. Ultimately I need it in a text file format. I used the sample code above, but it still does not have the spaces at the end when exported (manually).

Comment: Can you copy/paste out of the virtual client? If so, you could write it to the log and copy it out.

Comment: @George Not sure how you’re exporting, might want to be more clear. Also not sure what a virtual client means. But it’s probably  the method you’re using to write or whatever the data, SAS in some cases by default ignores trailing spaces. I can assure you they are there in the dataset, but you may need to output them explicitly.

Comment: @Joe The SAS Enterprise Guide software is not installed locally, instead it's a virtual version (like in the cloud or something...) The normal process of writing to a local disk does not work, it limited the write access to where the software is installed to. Even with the log the trailing spaces are ignored.